# Python splitlines() not working on DOS stdout

Tags: python, split, subprocess, newline

Python 3.7.9, running under Windows 7.

I need to work on some files that are in proprietary binary formats, and the company whose formats they are provides a set of DOS command-line .exe tools that can translate these files between the proprietary binary format and human-readable ASCII.

Problem is, the binary-to-ASCII conversion just dumps the ASCII output to the command line, and the utilities don't do wildcards or batching.  So it seemed like a good opportunity to try something new with my novice Python scripting skills.

I call the DOS tool using subprocess.check, and convert to string:

```
 testOutput = str(
            subprocess.check_output(
                [
                    r"C:/foo/foo.exe",
                    FilePath,
                ]
            )
        )
 outputTestResults.writelines(testOutput)
```

And this works (though I'm sure my code lacks elegance), except that the output text is just one line full of '\r\n', like this:

```
[1] = 1\r\n  [2] = 1\r\n  [3] = 1\r\n  [4] = 1\r\n  [5] = 1\r\n  [6] = 2\r\n  [7] = 2\r\n  [8] = 2\r\n  [9] = 18\r\n  [10] = 18\r\n  [11] = 18\r\n  [12] = 18\r\n  [13] = 18\r\n  [14] = 18\r\n  [15] = 18\r\n  [16] = 19\r\n  [17] = 19\r\n  [18] = 19\r\n  [19] = 19\r\n  [20] = 19\r\n  [21] = 19\r\n  [22] = 19\r\n  [23] = 19\r\n  [24] = 19\r\n  [25] = 19\r\n  [26] = 19\r\n  [27] = 19\r\n  [28] = 19\r\n  [29] = 19\r\n  [30] = 19\r\n  [31] = 19\r\n  [32] = 20\r\n  [33] = 20\r\n  [34] = 20\r\n  [35] = 21\r\n  [36] = 21\r\n  [37] = 21\r\n\r\n
```

This *looked* like something easy to fix, but... no go.  I've tried using splitlines() on the string before writing to my output file, but there is literally no effect.  The output with or without splitlines() is identical down to the last character.  I also tried using

```
   Output.replace(r"\r\n", "\\n")
```

with and without the 'r', also to no effect.  No errors, no scrambling, just... nothing.  I also tried write() rather than writelines(), just for the heck of it -- still no effect.

Addendum:  if I just use "foo.exe > output.txt" on the command line, I get what I would expect the output of splitlines() to be -- the same data, but with all the '\r\n' replaced by actual newlines (using Notepad++ as my editor in both cases)

Comment: There's a parameter to `check_output()` named [`universal_newlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) maybe setting this to True would provide a better result. In fact, given extra numbers, I kinda feel that either your output has been post-processed, or it's not exactly a string of newlines. Also you might probably want to play with `encoding` parameter, as DOS apps might return output encoded in CP866 or other localized code page.

Comment: Thanks!  Setting universal_newlines to True did the trick.  Oddly (or perhaps not oddly?), once I had that set, I no longer needed to use splitlines() or replace() on the string returned by subprocess().